# How to change messagesource with locale in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization, locale

I got problem with muitle messeage resources in spring boot like this:

this is my application.yml:

```
...
spring:
   messages:
      basename: i18n/messages_fr,i18n/messages_en
```

this is my test class:

```
public class MessageSourceTest {
@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

public String getMessage(String key, String keyLang) {
    Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(keyLang); // keyLang = "en", or "fr"
    String message = messageSource.getMessage(key, null, locale);
    return message;
}
```

}

Problem is that I always get message from i18n/messages_fr no matter what I set locale is "en" or "fr".

If I set application.yml to:

```
basename: i18n/messages_en,i18n/messages_fr
```

then I got message from i18n/messages_en

So, is there any way that i can get messages with dynamically locale.

(Just in backend, not set throught client with localeResolver and addInterceptors, something like this: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization)

Comment: Your base name must be `i18n/message` the correct file is loaded based on the `Locale`.

Comment: It's not work. I got exception org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'test.title' for locale 'en'.

Comment: If you copy pasted what I typed yes as it is missing an `s` ... `i18n/messages`.

Comment: I know, i use i18n/messages but it's not work.

Comment: Then you must have something weird in your setup. Have you tried `classpath:i18n/messages`?

Comment: If i config in application.yml then spring know where to look up right (I put i18n folder in src/main/resources) ?

Comment: because if I set only i18n/messages_fr or i18n/messages_en, it's still work

Comment: the problem with the `_fr` is that it basically is the convention for the `Locale` and it will (after appending the `Locale` try to locate `messages_fr_en` (for the `en` `Locale`). Which doesn't exists and thus do a fallback. You will also need to have a `i18n/messages.properties` containing the default messages.

Comment: I did add i18n/messages.properties and it's work now. So If I got many locale like "th" or "ru" so I have to define i18n/messages.properties, right? Do you have any link or doc to that?

Comment: That I documented in the Spring and Spring Boot reference guide (Spring Boot adds the requirement of having a `messages.properties` which is used to detect the presence of files (and it is used as the default).

Answer (score 0):

You should set `baseName` as `i18n/messages` not `i18n/messages_{lang}`.
Then with checking your `localeResolver`, spring decides which file should be read.